# Spark Dataset - NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing a weird exception when I try to create a Dataset and simply collecting data from it.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: Zero length BigInteger
    at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:302)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.UnsafeRow.getDecimal(UnsafeRow.java:405)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.writeFields_3_3$(generated.java:298)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(generated.java:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec$$anonfun$unsafeRows$1.apply(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec$$anonfun$unsafeRows$1.apply(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.unsafeRows$lzycompute(LocalTableScanExec.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.unsafeRows(LocalTableScanExec.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.LocalTableScanExec.executeCollect(LocalTableScanExec.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3278)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectAsList$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2739)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectAsList$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2738)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectAsList(Dataset.scala:2738)
    at com.temp.SparkTest.execute(SparkTest.java:85)
    at com.temp.SparkTest.main(SparkTest.java:104)
```

The executing code looks like this:

```
List<SimplePojo> list ...
Dataset<SimplePojo> ds = sparkSession.createDataset(list, Encoders.bean(SimplePojo.class))
ds.collectoAsList();
```

SimplePojo class contains one method **getSomething()** that apparently causes the exception. When I comment it out, everything works fine.

```
public class SimplePojo {

   private int id;
   private OtherPojo otherPojo = new OtherPojo();

   @Deprecated // required by park serialization. Use builder
   public SimplePojo(){}

   publi int getId(){
      return id;
   }

   public String getSomething() {
      return otherPojo.getSomething();
   }

   // sets ...
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

CAUSE:
Code above does not have attribute **something**. That causes the exception when the bean analyser (Introspector or something like this) find a *get* without a respective attribute (e.g: **getSomething** without attribute **something**). Creating an attribute and its set solved the exception but it did not resolve my problem. In my real code the "alone get" is getting a value from a composite attribute (OtherPojo).

Any idea on how to "say" to the analyser to ignore this method? (I tried @Transiente above the method but it did not work)

Comment: Could you provide a minimal code snippet that allows to reproduce the error?

Comment: Hello @RLM what serializer are you using?

Comment: Hi @AlexandrosBiratsis, I believe it uses Introspector from JDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I can't have *gets* that do not belong to the bean. I'm assuming it is a "bean format" expected by analyzers. *[Introspector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html)* gets crazy (in different ways depending on the Java version) when he finds a get without its respective attribute.

Since I could not find anyway to say to the analyzer "ignore this method", the solution is to avoid **gets** and **sets** that are not related to the bean attributes.